# Find and remove hashtags from a text in PHP

Tags: php, tags

I'm using PHP and would like to remove all hashtags from the end of a text (in this case: `#stack` `#overflow`) and put them in an array. 
Here is an example text:

> Lorem ipsum, http://example.com/#hello consetetur diam #nonumy sed
>   diam voluptua. #stack #overflow

This is the output I would like: (no hashtags at the end)

> Lorem ipsum, http://example.com/#hello consetetur diam #nonumy sed
>   diam voluptua.

How to do that?

Comment: What output you want.Use str_replace function

Answer (score 0):

To catch all hashtags in an array and remove it from that string you could do something like this:

```
 $string = 'Lorem ipsum, http://example.com/#hello consetetur diam #nonumy sed diam voluptua. #stack #overflow';

// match all hashtags and keep them in a named capture group, to easily get the key later.
preg_match_all('/(?P<hashtags>\#\w+)/', $string, $matches);
$string = str_replace($matches['hashtags'], '', $string);

var_dump($matches['hashtag']);
Array
(
    [0] => #hello
    [1] => #nonumy
    [2] => #stack
    [3] => #overflow 
)

var_dump($string);
// 'Lorem ipsum, http://example.com/ consetetur diam  sed diam voluptua.  ' (length=70)
```

If you like this way now you only have to figure out how to trim the exceeded white spaces.

-----EDIT2-----

If you want to capture only the last hashtag you must change the regexp to `'/(?P<hashtag>\#\w+$)/'`.

You may want to have an [explanation of the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/vT7oC0/1) I'm suggesting.

-----EDIT3-----

This new question is different and open a different view for the logic needed.

```
//keeping the same $string as above, you can easily get the substring after a dot (for example) til the end of the string with: 
$endOfString = substr($string, strrpos($string, '.') + 1);

// now you can use a regexp, or the 'explode()' function
preg_match_all('/(?P<hashtags>\#\w+)(?:\s)?/', $endOfString, $matches);
$string = str_replace($matches['hashtags'], '', $string);

var_dump($matches['hashtags']);
var_dump(trim($string));
```

As always you should play a bit on it to get something good for all your different cases

Comment: I would like to get only the hashtags at the end of the text, not the ones in an URL or within the text. How to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible to get all tags that are at the end of the text? Currently only the `#overflow` tag gets found. (I don't know if that helps but maybe it's possible to check for the following characters to find the end of the text?: `.,:;!?`)